# How could I use ajax toolkit controls in my web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to use some of Ajax toolkit controls in my ASP .net application but it seems that it does not work .
I want to use Modal popup in my form but the panel that must shown on popup , displayed on browser and the button do nothing . why it does not work ?
I'm codding in VB .net and there is my sample :

```
    <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="FieldItem.ascx.vb" Inherits="DataBaseWorker.FieldItem" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
    <link href="../Styles/FieldItem.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <div class="TitleDiv">

<span runat="server" id="lblIndex" class="IndexSpan">111</span>
<span runat="server" id="lblDelimeter" class="IndexSpan"> ) </span>
<span runat="server" id="lblTitle" class="TitleSpan">test</span>
<span runat="server" id="lblActiveState" class="TitleSpan">test</span>
<span runat="server" id="lblAlias" class="TitleSpan">test</span>
<asp:Button CssClass="buttonControl" ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="test" />
<asp:Button CssClass="buttonControl" ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="test" />
<asp:Button CssClass="buttonControl" ID="btnAddAlias" runat="server" Text="test" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
 CancelControlID="btnCancel" OkControlID="btnSubmitAlias" TargetControlID="btnAddAlias"
  PopupControlID="addAliasPlace" Drag="false">

  <Animations>
                <OnShowing>
                    <Sequence>
                        <StyleAction AnimationTarget="CloseButton" Attribute="display" Value="none" />
                        <Resize Duration="0" Height="50px" Width="50px" />
                    </Sequence>
                </OnShowing>
                <OnShown>
                    <Sequence>
                        <Parallel>
                            <FadeIn />
                            <Scale ScaleFactor="5" Center="True" />
                        </Parallel>
                        <StyleAction AnimationTarget="CloseButton" Attribute="display" Value="" />
                    </Sequence>
                </OnShown>    
                <OnHiding>
                    <Sequence>                            
                        <StyleAction AnimationTarget="CloseButton" Attribute="display" Value="none" />
                        <Parallel>
                            <FadeOut />
                            <Scale ScaleFactor="5" Center="True" />
                        </Parallel>
                    </Sequence>
                </OnHiding>            
        </Animations>

</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    </div>
<asp:Panel Visible="false"  runat="server" id="addAliasPlace" >

<div  class="AddAliasDiv">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAliasName" CssClass="TitleSpan" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button CssClass="buttonControl" ID="btnSubmitAlias" runat="server" Text="ثبت" />
    <asp:Button CssClass="buttonControl" ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="بازگشت" />
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Maybe this link will help you http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Comment: Thank you but I check it earlier and that's not work .I use that code and there is no error and I think that's for another problem .I don't no why but that's not work

Answer (score 0):

I can describe what i do when i use modal pop up.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnshowpopup" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />


<act:ModalPopupExtender ID="test" runat="server"
       TargetControlID="btnshowpopup"
       PopupControlID="addAliasPlace"
       CancelControlID="btnModalCancel"
       BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
       BehaviorID="addAliasPlace">
   </act:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And after i'm using js to show modal e.g.:

```
$find("addAliasPlace").show();
```

Comment: Thank you but i use this , in VB and C# and that's not work .

Comment: I suppose you have an element to trigger the action?

Comment: I'm set TargetControlID field to my control .is this enough ?

Comment: Did you include ScriptManager as @TrevorBrooks wrote?

Comment: yes,actually the code i was wrote is my user control and in the page that i use this UC , ScriptManager was included

Comment: Can you include js function please?

Comment: Then you must use System.Web.UI.ScriptControl

Comment: change on panel Visible="false" to style="display:none" and ClientIDMode="Static".

Answer (score 0):

If it is a User Control you must use System.Web.UI.ScriptControl.

From pietschsoft.com: *The ScriptControl base class tests the page for a ScriptManager control during the PreRender stage of the derived control. The ScriptControl base class also makes sure that the derived control calls methods of the ScriptManager control to register script during the Render event. This includes registering ScriptDescriptor objects for the ScriptControl when the Render method is called. The Render method makes sure that ScriptDescriptor objects are not rendered unless the ScriptControl itself is rendered. This enables a ScriptControl to work inside a closed WebPart control.*

See Also:
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/05/15/ASPNET_Create_AJAX_Server_Controls_using_the_ScriptControl_base_class

Comment: See Also:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co